# Trying to run ftpsync.pl from post-commit hook

Tags: perl, svn, post-commit

As the title says, I'm trying to ftpsync changed tree to our dev web server. On committing I get this error:

> post-commit hook failed (exit code 13)
>   with output: Cannot create syncfile
>   for time sync option at
>   /data/ftpsync/ftpsync.pl line 484.

I've tried looking at line 484 but Perl looks like a foreign language to me :)

What permissions do I need to set and where so that syncfile can be created?

Comment: Perl may look like Chinese to you, but presumably not to the people here you are asking; how about you show line 484?

Comment: Never mind, the curious can find it here: https://ftpsync.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ftpsync/trunk/ftpsync/src/ftpsync.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates the file in the current directory, and as far as I can tell doesn't change directories before that point.  The easiest thing to do would be to change directories to /tmp before starting the script (and specify a local directory in its args instead of using the default .).

Comment: You're right. Added o+w to directory specified in args and it works

Comment: another (potentially unwise) solution (don't do it!) would be changing the permissions on the current directory. *cd /tmp* first, as ysth suggests!